# Consume SOAP webservices using escaped xml as attribute

Tags: python, xml, soap, wsdl, suds

I am using suds to consume SOAP web services like this way:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://www.example.com?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
client.service.example(xml_argument)
```

If I call the method using this xml works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a><b description="Foo Bar"></b></a>
```

But If I add a quote (escaped) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a><b description="Foo &quot; Bar"></b></a>
```

I get the following error (from the webservice):

> Attribute name "Bar" associated with an element type "b" must be
>   followed by the ' = ' character.

I am using version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Am I not using suds.client in the proper way? any suggestions?

---

UPDATE:

I have already contacted customer support, emailed them my escaped XML and they told me that it works for them, so probably is caused due a bad use from suds in my side. I'll give a try with [PySimpleSOAP](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is mostly a guess, but the error you are quoting seems to be generated from the XML well-formedness checker on the machine providing the service.

It seems that on that side of the cable they are getting something like:

```
<a><b description="Foo" Bar"></b></a>
```

(`&quot;` converted to `"`) and thus they are telling you that you should instead send something like:

```
<a><b description="Foo" Bar="..."></b></a>
```

which is clearly not what you want.

AFAIK your XML is well formed (just tested [here](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) for extra safety), so either there is a bug in suds (which would surprise me, given the magnitude of the bug and the maturity of the package) or there is a bug on the server providing the service (possibly a "too early conversion" from XML entities to regular chars).

Again: lot of speculation and few hard facts here, but I still HTH! :)

Comment: Not sure if I am being confused by the docs (I have no previous experience with SOAP), but found this https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/TipsAndTricks#IncludingLiteralXML where I understand that I should pass an Element instance instead the xml in form of string. I'll try that, thanks for your response and guesses :)

Comment: This does not is what I was exactly looking for, but it helped in some way, thanks :) this was the solution I was looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619328/consume-wsdl-url-with-xml-with-escaped-chars-as-argument/7677216#7677216