# Consume WSDL url with XML with escaped chars as argument

Tags: python, xml, django, soap, wsdl

I am executing a method of a SOAP web service which receives 3 string arguments with suds library.

The first string argument should be an XML and the other 2 an username and password, this is my semi-working implementation.

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://www.jonima.com.mx:3014/sefacturapac/TimbradoService?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
client.service.timbrado(XML_AS_STRING_HERE, 'PRUEBA1', '12345678')
```

When the first parameter contains an escaped character (ampersand, quotes, apostrophe, less than, bigger than) method does not work because the server interprets the text as if it were unescaped. If doesn't contain any of those chars the method works great

XML example without ampersand works
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1990697/no_amp.xml

XML example with ampersand doesn't work
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1990697/with_amp.xml

Any idea how can I pass XML with escaped chars?

It doesn't have to rely on suds but in python. 
I am using python 2.6 (How ever it could be with 2.7 if required)

I am also using Django framework, don't know if that could be useful.

---

Extra Info:

- I have no access to modify SOAP server
- Customer support told me my    xml are correct and that they work for
  them, so the error is in my    implementation (or somewhere in suds?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the suds library is the culprit here.  When you send your escaped xml into suds as a parameter to the `client.service.timbrado` method it also escapes it.  However, it sees that you have escaped the ampersand already like this:

```
...
descripcion="EJE&amp;MPLO"
...
```

And it does not escape it further (although it should).  You should run your escaped xml through `xml.sax.saxutils.escape` before passing it to `client.service.timbrado`.

This should result in xml snippet above looking like this:

```
...
descripcion="EJE&amp;amp;MPLO"
...
```

When I run your code with the doubly-escaped xml, I receive the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:timbradoResponse xmlns:ns2="http://sefactura.com">
            <return>
                <status>401 - Fecha y hora de generación fuera de rango</status>
            </return>
        </ns2:timbradoResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

It is an error regarding your data (date and time of generation out of range), not about the format of the xml.

Comment: indeed :)  glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You are easily able to 'escape' any XML values before it goes over to the service. Check out http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml

```
>>> from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
>>>
>>> escape("< & >")
'&lt; &amp; &gt;'
```

This has worked for me in the past to do exactly what you're describing, pass XML data over a the net to a page.

According to http://www.xmlnews.org/docs/xml-basics.html#references , just escaping the data before its sent will work just fine.

To work off of your example XML

```
...
descripcion="EJE&MPLO"
...
```

after it goes through will be

```
...
descripcion="EJE&amp;MPLO"
...
```

Comment: The xml argument is escaped correctly, if you see the source of the given http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1990697/with_amp.xml you'll see a correctly escaped XML. Cheers...

Comment: since you are already escaping the characters, there is nothing further you can do on your side AND the service is working... this looks like to be a bug with suds... tho a quick look at their bug tracker doesn't list this particular bug.  Can you try to do what you're wanting to do with another service (to see if your method works)? You could probably very easily switch from using suds to something else (suds just really is an xml parser at the end of the day... plenty of they laying around)

Comment: Thankyou, the trick finally was to escape again it was matter of tick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping them twice?

If the service is broken, you should file a bug-report and take precautions so you will notice it when it gets fixed and your workaround should be removed.

Comment: Thankyou, If I could mark more than one option as valid answer this will also be applied, so bad I can only give an upvote.